Why is tempfile.gettempdir() giving me the wrong path?
I have code that is trying to create a directory in my temp folder.
My code is :
temp = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "HDD")
print(temp)

And it prints:
C:\Users\JEFFSA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\HDD

The error I receive is this:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\JEFFSA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\HDD\\Path.txt'

The code that the error points to is:
with open(temp + "\\Path.txt", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(path)

I checked and my temp folder is actually this:
C:\Users\JeffSandor\AppData\Local\Temp
Why would the tempfile.gettempdir() give me a different path than it actually is?

"I have code that is trying to create a directory in my temp folder." - looks like you completely forgot the "create a directory in my temp folder" part, and skipped right to trying to put stuff in the directory you didn't create.

@user2357112 That could be, I haven't had any issues with that when working in the same directory as my code. Let me see if that fixes it.

Thank you so much @user2357112. I totally just overlooked that, For some reason I thought that if there isn't the directory then it creates it to put the document in. If you wanted to put that as an answer I'll mark it as the resolution.

You're trying to put stuff in a subdirectory of your temp folder, but you never actually made that subdirectory. You need to make it first.
tempfile.gettempdir() gave you a valid path. The JEFFSA~1 thing is an 8.3 filename, a weird backward compatibility thing that exists due to file and directory name length restrictions on old Windows and DOS versions.
